# Using MPMoviePlayerController - Can we Add Custom Buttons?

Tags: iphone, video, button, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am creating an app that plays a video. This video is promotional material for a company. It details some of their products. What I want to do is create a button that can "jump" to a specific product. If you click the Product A button, you can jump to the section of the video about Product A.

I've got a basic (and I mean basic) knowledge of how MPMoviePlayerController works, but I don't know how to customise it yet. Can this custom button work and if so how?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes just add them to the MPMoviePlayerController's view property (thats if you are not using it fullscreen like me: [Unable to add overlay to MPMoviePlayerController in SDK 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104662/unable-to-add-overlay-to-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-sdk-4-1))