# Unable to add overlay to MPMoviePlayerController in SDK 4.1

Tags: iphone

This is a follow-on from: [Overlay on top of Streaming MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356540/overlay-on-top-of-streaming-mpmovieplayercontroller)

I've seen the various threads about checking for a new Window and then using that to apply my custom views to my fullscreen video however in SDK 4.1 this doesnt appear to be the case.

I have tried a timer and listening for UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification but in neither case does [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] ever contain more than 1 item.

I have tried adding my view to the players view property which works fine when displayed in place, but not when fullscreen, even if I add it in moviePlayBackDidEnterFullScreen event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem a few weeks ago:

It seems this method does not work on the iPad (I havent checked iPhone SDK 4>) so in order to get round it you can do the following.

After adding your video and setting to fullscreen you can add your controls directly to the UIWindow (e.g. `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] addSubView:myView]`), they will then appear on top of your video video.

The only problem I have found with this is that they don't obey the orientation rules of the view and I have manually had to program the rotation code in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method of the view.